# Remove physics body

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

Is there a way to remove a physics body in swift 3?

All I found was `myNode.phyisicsBody = nil` but it doesn't work in swift 3

> "Nil cannot be assigned to type SKPhysicsBode"

In fact, by default my `scene.sks` has a child Scene who has a `physicsBody`, a small dot at the center, and it's this one I would remove

[image: <code>The code to get the physicsBody</code>]
[image: <code>scene.sks with "Scene" child</code>]
[image: Small dot that I don't want]

Comment: Did you try the `removeFromParent` function?

Comment: Don't have this one. Only "remove" I have is    `removeObserver`

Comment: Just tried this line `myNode.physicsBody = nil ` in playground, it is working well. Maybe you could show us some more code. How did you create the node and `physicsBody`? Also, notice the typo **physics**

Comment: Remove the `!`!

Comment: Ah, nice one...
Sometimes you don't see something that is just in front of you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried the following code in playground, you can `myNode.physicsBody = nil`

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "elephant")

spriteNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spriteNode.texture!,
                                       size: spriteNode.texture!.size())
spriteNode.physicsBody = nil // No Error
```

From [Apple API about physicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483117-physicsbody):

> The default value is nil, which indicates that the node does not participate in the physics simulation at all. If a physics body is provided, when the scene’s physics are simulated, the physics body updates the node’s position and rotates the node.

I would say, check where you initially created the `physicsBody`, and make sure it is optional.

**Edit**

> ```
> SceneObject!.physicsBody! = nil
> ```

This cannot work! by using the `!` you are telling the compiler that it is not `nil`

Change it to

```
SceneObject!.physicsBody = nil
```